# Android: Error trying to edit button text after thread sleep

Tags: textview, android

(programming Android in Eclipse) I am trying to set up a delay in changing the text in a button. I am getting errors only after there is a delay and the text needs to be changed. Here is the simplified code without a while loop:

```
final Button button_target = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_target);        
    Thread textChange = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run(){
            button_target.setText("fog");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}                
        }
    });
    textChange.start();
```

And now here is the code where a change of text on the button is required *after* the sleep which now causes and error and exit (forced):

```
 final Button button_target = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_target);        
    Thread textChange = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run(){
            button_target.setText("cat");
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}                
            button_target.setText("dog");
        }
    });
    textChange.start();
```

what am I doing to cause the error? Is there another method that I should do to be able to invoke a sleep or delay to the thread so that a text change operation can be performed?

(the actual code has a while loop but I believe this form puts the error in highlight)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change UI stuff on a thread like setText(), it must be done on the UIThread. See AsyncTask for more informations :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> Add more information

You can use THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR with AsyncTask in function of which versions of Android you use like this :

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){} 
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        button_target.setText("dog");
    }

};

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: looks like I overlooked something fundamental... eek. is it ok to have a while loop in `doInBackground` that continues endlessly until a condition is satisfied from the user? does that block the whole AsyncTask object?

Comment: I am not sure AsyncTask is the best way because the link you gave says: "If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask." So there should be a better way.